# General formulation of polynomial invariants.

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, invariant-theory, symmetric-functions

Reading this work https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.06452.pdf, I'm wondering if it's true that any *fundamental invariant* polynomial $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^{N_{inv}}$ can be written as

$$f_i(x) = \sum_{g \in G}\psi(g \cdot x)$$

where $\psi(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{b_i}$ for fixed exponents $b_i$. Here it is considered $G \le S_n$ and for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$g \cdot x := (x_{\sigma_g(1)}, \dots x_{\sigma_g(n)})$$

is just permuting the coordinates.

So in this case I guess we are considering *symmetric polynomials*: for example, given $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $S_3$ then I should be able to express the *elementary symmetric  polynomials* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)) using this form. In particular we have

$$e_0(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1 , $$

$$e_1(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1+x_2+x_3 ,$$

$$e_2(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 ,$$

$$e_3(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2x_3. $$

Is it actually possible to describe all these fundamentals by assuming any $G \le S_3$? Can you eventually help me to see that?

Comment: For symmetric polynomials, $G=S_n$.

Comment: Yes it is true, up to constant $\psi$ is the Reynolds operator. It is projector into invariant ring

Comment: So the fundamental invariants for symmetric polynomials are given by the reynold operator? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I dont sure what is the findamental invariants but  algebra of symmentric  polynomials  is generated by the Reydolds operator, for example  a generating set for $S_3$ is $ \psi(x_1)=x_1+x_2+x_3$, $ \psi(x_1^2)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ $ \psi(x_1^3)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ But for invariant neural network more interesting ( in my opinion ) is the case   infinite rotation groups $SO(2)$  for example

Comment: Correct $\psi(x_1^3)=x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$

Comment: Why do you take only sums for generating set of $S_3$?